# How do I get an object from a String

Tags: java, string, object, email, stringify

I am working on a project, where users can write other users mails. The mail-class looks currently like this:

```
public class Mail
{
    /*
     * Fields
     */
    private final String _content;
    private final String _sender;
    private final String _date;
    private final String _topic;

    /**
     * Constructor of the Mail-class.
     *
     * @param mail The mail as a string representation.
     */
    public Mail(String mail)
    {
        _content = ...;
        _sender = ...;
        _date = ...;
        _topic = ...;
    }

    // And all the getters.

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
      // Make the reperentation as a String
    }
```

Now, the problem is, that I need to save all the mails into a .yml userdata file. For me, the simplest way to do this is to firstly convert every mail to a String and then save all mails into a `List<String> mails` which will be written directly into the .yml where I can access and read the list of String with ease. Now, once I start the server, all mails should be converted back into the object-representation. The question is, how can I save the mail-Object as a String and load it, that I can operate using those mail objects.

My first ideas were something like this `sender#date#topic#content` and then splitting the String via `String.split("#");`. But when I do this, I need to ban the `#` character for the content and the topic. The date and the username will never contain `#`. I don't want to ban any character. Unfortunately I have nothing found on my researches so far on how to solve this task.

Comment: why yaml instead of just...a file with the email? it's a plain text format already, the to and from string lgorithm has been documented from day 1 (and on a java note: remove those _ from your field names. The `private` already strongly types it as such)

Comment: Use [a library such as jackson](https://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-yaml-files-in-java-with-jackson/) to handle the reading and writing of the actual yaml. Don't reinvent the wheel. You might want to switch to xml or another format that is more suitable for bigger payloads.

Comment: I use .yml because I save everything related to the users into the datafile (The server is basically using yml everywhere). Every user has its own UUID and has some preferences and other data which should persist. Yes, I could create a file for every mail but, is that a better solution, than writing it into a list which can be accesst with one single command?

Comment: @1somorph i don't see how yml benefits you there, the same thing can be done with xml or json. In yaml, you even need to escape linebreaks, imho it's not an ideal format for larger texts.

Comment: Use separate properties for each field.

Comment: How about sender###date###topic###content and and then splitting the `String` via `String.split("###");`

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc The problem is that a message with '###' contained will be also split. That way I have to ban users from using '###' in their topic or content.

Comment: it makes sense that doing this in xml could be a better solution but the problem is that I 1. never made anything with xml and 2. I already implemented the whole system with .yml, switching everything would take ages to make it work and to refactor it..

Comment: Fine.  Make it #################.  Or #$%^&.   At some number of hash marks, a user will not type it.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Just in case you missunderstood me: I dont want to ban anything. I dont know what my users will type in.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is use XML or JSON to markup the object and convert it to a string for you. There are tons of libraries you can use to do that. They all operate in roughly the same manner: add an annotations to your fields and class.